# javascript loop (for statement) slows down after 2.1 billion iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, v8, slowdown

I was trying to benchmark javascript and .net core in order to choose a server side framework for  providing some specific restful services which needed to iterate large arrays(***about 2.1 billion***). while working on a simple code, I realized node has strange behavior after a particular number iteration. I repeated on multiple platforms and reached same result. tested platforms were:

- macOS catalina (nodeJS v.12.18) intel  core i9 4ghz 6 core
- linux centos 7 (nodeJS v.12.18) vm intel core i9 4ghz 2 core
- google chrome Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Mozilla firefox version 78.2

[running video shows surprisingly increase process time about two times from 300ms to 600ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37E6.gif)

### sample codes:

#### 1. nodejs:

```js
var cnt = 0;
var logPeriod=100000000;
var max=10000000000;
for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  if (i % logPeriod === 0) {
    // var end = Date.now();
    if (i !== 0) {
      console.timeEnd(cnt*logPeriod, i);
      cnt++;
    }
    console.time(cnt*logPeriod);
  }
}
```

#### 2.browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function doloop() {
        var cnt = 0;
        var logPeriod = 100000000;
        var max = 10000000000;
        for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          if (i % logPeriod === 0) {
            // var end = Date.now();
            if (i !== 0) {
              console.timeEnd(cnt * logPeriod, i);
              cnt++;
            }
            console.time(cnt * logPeriod);
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="doloop()">doloop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly the `cnt*logPeriod` is eventually going out the true integer range (31 bits) and over to the floating point representation of larger integers, and hence the slow down.

Comment: Wait, you really have a use case for your application where your server needs to iterate an array of 2.1 billion entries?

Comment: @GetSet All numbers are floating point in JS.

Comment: They're treated as regular (no decimal) integers up to 31 bits. At least from what I gleaned before making the earlier comment. I'll see if I can find an official reference tho

Comment: @GetSet I don't believe so. JavaScript uses floating point arithmetic and treats all numbers as floats all the time.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number): ***A number literal like 37 in JavaScript code is a floating-point value, not an integer. There is no separate integer type in common everyday use. (JavaScript now has a BigInt type, but it was not designed to replace Number for everyday uses. 37 is still a Number, not a BigInt.)***

Comment: Also from that same link: ***The JavaScript Number type is a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value, like double in Java or C#. This means it can represent fractional values, but there are some limits to what it can store. A Number only keeps about 17 decimal places of precision; arithmetic is subject to rounding. The largest value a Number can hold is about 1.8×10308. Numbers beyond that are replaced with the special Number constant Infinity.***

Comment: Ok. Yes. However on the implementation of the "engine" behind the scenes, for efficiency, integers of the norm type are used when in the appropriate bit range. It depends on the implementation of the engine. Hence this could very well be the source of the slow down in the OP's environments.

Comment: And another [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures): ***ECMAScript has two built-in numeric types: Number and BigInt (see below).

The Number type is a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value (numbers between -(253 − 1) and 253 − 1). In addition to representing floating-point numbers, the number type has three symbolic values: +Infinity, -Infinity, and NaN ("Not a Number").***

Comment: @GetSet That's possibly true, but just speculation. In fact casting a float from the JS engine into an int for the native implementation could save a bit of storage memory but slow down the performance, so I wouldn't think that's the case also. And, while it is true that the max 32 bit int is 2.1 billion, most OS' use 64 bit ints these days so the max int would be much higher.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: yes, the JavaScript spec requires that all numbers behave as if they were doubles. But engines can and do use more efficient internal representations, as long as they ensure that this difference is not observable in behavior (only by providing a speed and/or memory savings benefit). Source: I work on such an engine.

Comment: @GetSet: you're spot on; except it's not only `cnt*logPeriod` but also `i` itself that goes out of int32 range.

Comment: i did same test on windows 10, intel core i5 7400, same result was obtained.

Comment: @AhadRafatTalebi: that's expected. OS and CPU don't matter in the sense that floating-point arithmetic is always slower than integer arithmetic; only the magnitude of the difference might depend on hardware (I'm seeing about 4x on my machine: 120 vs 540 ms). It also doesn't matter whether it's a 64-bit OS: the "use int32 internally" trick doesn't scale to int64, because possible int32 values are a subset of double values, but int64 values are not: they would be *too precise*, so if an engine used them, that would be a bug. It's tricky :-)

Comment: @jmrk many thanks for your very nice answer. you are right. it seems that is not processor, core even operating system issue because results are same. its architecture issue. I have to add an other tier into application for large arithmetic tasks.

Comment: @GetSet Exactly, its an architecture problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V8 developer here.

V8's optimizing compiler generates code that uses plain 32-bit integers for numbers as long as it can. Once a number exceeds int32 range (or precision requirements, i.e. when it needs to hold fractional values), then such optimized code is thrown away (or never generated in the first place) and 64-bit doubles are used instead, as the JavaScript spec requires. Arithmetic operations (even something as simple as `i++`) are slower on 64-bit doubles than they are on 32-bit integers, that's just what hardware does.

In terms of behavior, this internal difference is unobservable: numbers always behave *as if* they were 64-bit doubles. But that doesn't mean that engines actually always use 64-bit doubles under the hood: as you can see here, there is a significant performance benefit when the engine can get away with using 32-bit integers internally.

> choose [JavaScript or .net for] restful services which needed to iterate large arrays(about 2.1 billion)

That's an easy decision: use .net. V8 (and hence Node) won't let you create arrays with 2.1 billion elements, because the per-object size limit is far lower than that. Sure, `var a = new Array(2_100_000_000)` will evaluate just fine, but that's because it doesn't actually allocate all that memory. Start filling in elements and watch it crash after a while :-)

And if your actual arrays won't be that big after all, then please define a benchmark that's closer to your actual workload, because its results will be more representative and hence more useful for your decision-making.

Comment: very good description of the v8 structure. you are right but just as a final try, do you think, is it possible to use new feature  [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for this case?

Comment: How to increase the per-object size limit? `node --stack-size=100000000000000000 --max-old-space-size=65536 -p "Array(2_100_000_000).fill(null).length"` didn't help. Do I need a custom build? Which constant should I change?

Comment: Interestingly, QuickJS does not have the limit by default: `qjs -e "Array(2_100_000_000).fill(null)"` succeeded after eating up 31.3G of memory.

Comment: @AhadRafatTalebi: I don't understand for what exactly you want to use BigInts here; for the loop variable `i`? You certainly _can_ use them; being a rather new feature they haven't received as much optimization effort as numbers yet, so BigInt-heavy code tends to be slower than Number-based code for now.

Comment: @AlanLiang: you can't increase V8's per-object size limit. It is expected that different engines have different limits. They may be self-imposed arbitrary limits, or they might arise from internal implementation design choices. V8 only uses 30 bits for an object's size, so each object must fit into 1G. We prefer it that way because (1) using more bits would increase metadata overhead, and (2) in most scenarios, as a user you wouldn't even _want_ a single object to use more memory than that. FWIW, TypedArrays can get bigger.

Comment: @jmrk: Yes, performance is very important factor for us in this case. If BigInt is causes overhead, it wont be suitable for this use case. As you suggest, best way is choosing C# . So It was very helpful answer indeed.